# Why don't notifications appear in the system tray?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can send push notifications to my Android phone and simulator when my app is running. (I can tell that they arrive because my app crashes.)

So why don't notifications appear in the system tray? They did a couple of times when I looked at my phone hours later. I have no idea why that happened.

I'm sending them from the Firebase Cloud Messaging screen and it says the messages are "Completed".

Here's some code...

```
[Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
    public class FirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

        public override void OnTokenRefresh()
        {
            var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;

            Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        }
    }

    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class CCFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Hi Mum!");
        }
    }
```

Both of these events can broken on in the debugger.

In the manifest...

```
<application android:label="My app">
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

Comment: can you show your code!

Comment: Why would that make a difference?

Comment: we are not god !

Comment: If a device receives a notification from Firebase and it's not running (although it's not force stopped), does the code make a difference to what happens? (I've added some code.)

Comment: obviously ! without seeing code how we can identify your error !

Comment: But if the app is not running, how can the code affect the notifications?

Comment: it will crashed after receiving notification !

Comment: follow this https://www.codementor.io/flame3/send-push-notifications-to-android-with-firebase-du10860kb

Comment: ok, thanks kdblue. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: i think you are trying `firebase` first time!

Comment: Yes. Well that article covers pretty much what I've done and I don't see why my devices aren't showing notifications in the system tray. Does the app need to be in release mode or something?

Comment: no ! its not matter , check your manifests its not receiver it will be service , see in tutorial link !

Comment: OK, some have appeared. So, when do the notifications appear in the system tray? Is it only when the app is not visibly running or do they not appear in the system tray if the app is not visible but appears in the list of apps screen?

Comment: by default one appears only when app is in background !

Comment: So what's background? Does background include when it's not visible but in the list of apps that you can scroll through - (I think it's the menu button that takes you there).

Comment: Oh I've answered my own question, yes they appear in the system tray if the app is in the apps list. "Never Give Up!!!" I like it!

Comment: hahahaha , no matter what i never give up !

Comment: add some more details!! are you sen message through fcm console or else where?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design with Firebase.

The notifications will show if the app is in the background, but not if it is visible. The actual receipt of the underlying push message, and display of the notification are handled by the Firebase library.

This is different to the older Google Cloud Messaging which always delivers to the app whether it is foreground or background.

(Community wiki answer based on comments in a long thread. Pls edit to add more detail.)